# Finding in which column of a datagrid is a specific control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I got a datagrid on which I put a MouseButtonEventHandler.

Everytime I click on a row, my event is raised.

What I would like to do is handle that event only when the event was raised on a particular column.

I can get the control that raised the event via e.OriginalSource. But I don't known how I must do something like:

```
if(_dg.Column["TheRightColumn"].Contains(e.OriginalSource)) //Do the job
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to make the column a template column? If so place a control (maximised grid) in the template and handle your click event on that control, rather than the whole grid.